# Why does jQuery-Lint tell me .css() isn't a function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-lint

jQuery-Lint is throwing the following error for me:

```
$(".around_divboxes").css is not a function
   $('.around_divboxes').css('marginLeft', '0px');
```

Can someone tell me *why* it throws this error, and how to solve it?

Comment: It definitely is a function. Very strange. I did notice that you have marginLeft however, which should be margin-left.

Comment: I have seen this when the jquery core js has not been loaded. Make sure the jquery.js is loading on the page.

Comment: @Ant the "marginLeft" is correct :) jquery is a little different you cant use "margin-left"

Comment: @jen I think your Comment solve the problem, I tested it on "onLoad" if I switch to "onDomReady" it dosnt trow a error. Write your anser below, that I can vote it for best, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this when the jquery core js has not been loaded. Make sure the jquery.js is loading on the page.

Comment: @dmakerman see comment above by OP that told me to post the comment as answer